# Counting img tags line by line

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to count all `<img>` tags inside a string line by line but cant figure it out.
i've already made to split the string line by line, then count the `<img>` tags after it.

Example :

```
$string = "
some text <img src="" /> some text <img src="" /> some text  <img src="" /> some text \n
some text <img src="" /> some text `<img src="" /> some text  <img src="" /> some text ";
```

now my code is
first to split it line by line

```
$array = explode("\n", $string);
```

now count how many `<img>` tags are there in the first line of var string.

```
$first_line = $array['0'];
```

i was using preg_match() to get match for img tags.

```
$img_line = preg_match("#<img.+>#U", $array['0']);
echo count($img_line);
```

this wont work for me, in the $string there are 3 `<img src="">` per line but my code gives me only 1.

any hint or tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a simple `explode` line by line, this will give you the count:

```
$explode = explode('<img ', $array[0]);
echo count($explode);
```

Comment: $explode = explode("#<img.+>#U", $array[0]);
echo count($explode); this are the example ive tried before. will try yours.

Comment: @Vhanjan: the explode function accepts only a literal string as argument, not a regex. To do the same with a regex, use `preg_split`.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: yes i know thats why im having trouble with this. but now i got it i use preg_match_all for this.

Comment: Actually, `count( $explode )` gives one more than the count, and by the way, you could just use [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Got it..

After splitting the string per line.

```
$first_line = $array['0'];
$match = preg_match_all("#<img.+>#U", $first_line, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo count($matches['0']);
```

the code above will return this..

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
                [2] => 
            )
    )

3
```

Comment: Note that you can use this better pattern: `#<img [^>]*>#` (no need to use the greedy/lazy switcher, and less backtracks)

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: in regex .+ means optional right? but i am confused with this [^]. sorry have some poor knowledge with regex.

Comment: `*` means zero or more times. `+` means one or more times. `[^>]` means all characters but `>`. it's useful to negate a character class.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: I see, this will going to be useful for me, as I still need to learn more bout regex ^_^, ive tried your suggested pattern and gives me the same result as the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```php
<?php
$string = <<<TXT
some text <img src="" /> some text <img src="" /> some text  <img src="" /> some text
some text <img src="" /> some text <img src="" /> some text  <img src="" /> some text
TXT;

$lines = explode("\n", $string);
// For each line
$count = array_map(function ($v) {
  // If one or more img tag are found
  if (preg_match_all('#<img [^>]*>#i', $v, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    // We return the count of tags.
    return count($matches);
  }
}, $lines);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 3 // Line 1
    [1] => 3 // Line 2 
)
*/
print_r($count);
```

Here, `PREG_SET_ORDER`stores the results in a single level (first capture to index `$matches[0]`, second capture to index `$matches[1]`). Thus, we can easily retrieve the number of catches.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = 'some text <img src="" /> some text <img src="" /> some text  <img src="" /> some text \n
some text <img src="" /> some text `<img src="" /> some text  <img src="" /> some text ';

$count = preg_match_all("/<img/is", $string, $matches);

echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: Your solution counts the number of occurrences of the tag throughout the text, however, @Vhanjan looking to count per line.